# What 2-letter words were added/removed in each eddition of the OSPD?

Tags: scrabble

It's pretty easy to find a [current 2-letter word list](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Scrabble/Two_Letter_Words) for Scrabble.  Where can I find the changes that happened to the 2-letter word list in each version of the Official Scrabble Player's Dictionary?

For example, I know that 4th edition added QI and ZA (which were both a big deal because neither Q nor Z had 2-letter words prior to that).  6th edition added EW and OK.

Most articles about new editions just show the highlights and not the full word delta ([example](https://time.com/5404583/new-words-added-to-scrabble-dictionary/), [example](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2019/may/02/scrabble-change-of-mindset-allows-use-of-ok)).  [scrabbleplayers.org has the delta from 3rd to 4th edition,](https://scrabbleplayers.org/w/OSPD4) but not any of the others.

Where can I find the whole list of changes by edition?